# Signaling all active threads (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, synchronization

I am faced with a design issue regarding thread synchronization in C++, Windows.

I am writing a server application that starts one *listening* thread, which should stay active the whole time while the server is up.
When the listening thread gets a *connect* request, it opens a CONTROL socket and starts a new **control** thread. 
This thread is used to send control data between server and a client, initializing server and all the background software to specific client data and starting data processing.

If the initialization (via control socket) is successful, the **control** thread will open a new socket, DATA socket, which is then used to pass data from server to client. It will also start two new threads, one which is sending on this new, DATA socket, and the other, which is receiving on the CONTROL socket, waiting if the client wants to terminate connection.

When client terminates connection ungracefully, by terminating application without the call to function which sends the server message to close the connection, here is what should happen:

- Any of the threads in execution can detect this event. They will get some sort of error (WSAECONNRESET) while sending or receiving on DATA/CONTROL socket and should then signal all the other threads that they should stop executing (except for the server listening thread).

Which is the most natural way to achieve this type of behavior?

(I am using winsock (winsock2.h) for networking, and standard windows api (windows.h) for threading)

Comment: Seems like you're using a lot of threads.

Comment: Any constructive comment on how this would be elegantly altered is welcome. 
This is my first multithreaded app and I am not familiar with the usual way to handle these kinds of problems. Would you please post an idea regarding the improvement of the original idea?
The server must be able to send via data and control socket simultaneously. How can I achieve this if I do not separate this in 2 threads?
Also, the recv and send function exibit blocking behavior and that is why I have decided to separate this into two threads - one receiving, and the other sending on socket.

Comment: @construKction: See WSAWaitForMultipleEvents. `recv` isn't blocking if you've already waited for the "data available" event.

Comment: Forcibly close all open sockets.  That's going to cause all blocking socket calls to return with an error code, allowing all threads to exit.  Not terribly different from just having your main() function exit and let the CRT terminate the process.  Saying goodbye nicely is usually preferred.

Comment: Abandon blocking sockets.  Use overlapped IO.  See http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/io-strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a multi-threaded winsock server, you should be looking into IO completion ports.  Using an IO completion port is the most scalable way to write a network service on the windows platform.

IO completion port based winsock servers use asynchronous communication, so instead of blocking on a socket, your threadpool receives completion packets when something interesting happens.

In any case, you'll be using [WSARecv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  When WSARecv returns non zero, call [WSAGetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If you don't have [WSA_IO_PENDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSA_IO_PENDING), then switch on the error and look for the [winsock error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you're interested in.

The winsock error code WSA_OPERATION_ABORTED indicates that a socket has closed, although there are others (e.g. WSAECONNABORTED).

Would suggest a good text on the subject (e.g. Windows via C/C++).

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSAEventSelect() function to associate event object with socket and create one event object for your events, then use these event objects in WaitForMultipleObjects() function, so your thread can wait for socket events and your custom events.